# How can I get the displayed value of a cell in MS Excel ( for text that was converted to dates)?

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2010, worksheet-function, date-time

How can I get the displayed value of a cell in MS Excel ( for text that was converted to dates)?

### Excel File Origin

I have an Excel file that was originally a CSV file. At this time I don't have access to the original CSV file. When the CSV file was originally opened in Excel, many of cells in the `Date` column were automatically converted.

### Example Values

Here is an example of some of the items from the `Date` column ( spacing represents left and right aligned cells, mostly to show that the second date was not converted):

***exhibit 1:***

```
        3/1/71
12/01/1882
Fall 1988
          1993
```

And if I choose one of those cells and right click and select formatting I will get different things:

```
m/d/yy
General
General
General
```

### Possible Logic

So looks like excel hasn't converted the 12/01/1882 date - maybe because it is "too old" or maybe for another reason.

If I select the whole column and change it to "General" formatting it then gives me this ( text left aligned, numbers right aligned):

```
       25993
12/01/1882
Fall 1988
        1993
```

### What I Want

I'd like to have one column where I have the format set to "General" or "Text" and it would have the dates that were displayed from **exhibit 1** above.

I saw [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19401403/get-the-cell-value-as-how-it-was-presented-in-excel) about using a DataFormatter class (looks like Java?) and some similar questions that use Macros and VB scripting - but if at all possible I would really like a way to use an excel function to do this.

### What I've tried

I've tried using these things which have not worked:

`CONCATENATE` - to get the date field, and prepend it with a space
`INDIRECT(ADDRESS(ROW(),5))` - get the value indirectly
`VALUE()` - get the "value' of the cell - opposite of what I want
`TEXT()` - can explicitly specify format but still can't make it work
`CELL()` - can be used to get cell information such as "contents" - no luck with this but I did see that I could use it also to get `format` which would tell me if the cell is displayed as a number or as "general" which could then possibly used with an `IF` function somehow to convert a number that is displayed as a date back to an actual date... possibly?

**Copy Paste Method**

One method I saw which seems to work is to select the values, copy and paste them into notepad, and then copy and paste them back into excel (it effectively gives the displayed value - which is what I want )

The only problem is that I would like to have a function to do this because the excel sheet has a few hundred thousand rows in it.

Comment: If notepad is a solution you should be able to just cipy the cells and then "paste special" and choose text only

Comment: @MattiasÅslund - yes but for hundreds of thousands of rows is the only issue...

Comment: How about just selecting the proper date format for the column and then left justify the cells? It will look right although some cells are actually still dates

Comment: Thanks - I need the actual values as text - the file is going to get imported into another program

Comment: [**Microsoft Excel (using the default 1900 Date System) cannot display dates before the year 1900**, although this is not due to a two-digit integer being used to represent the year](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Year_1900_problem). [How to Work with Dates Before 1900 in Excel](http://www.exceluser.com/formulas/earlydates.htm)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you have shown us the full range of possible formats, this should work:

```
=TEXT(A1, IF(CELL("format",A1)="D4", "m/d/yy", "General"))
```

If you have date formats other than m/d/yy, add tests for them.

Comment: Not a lot of explanation, and doesn't seem to solve any of the general problem of getting what is displayed on screen as the result of a formula.  Possibly a help in guessing which unrelated pre-canned format to use but not sure how it adds to the question.

Comment: (1) Is there some specific part of this that you don’t understand? (2) What do you mean by “the general problem of getting what is displayed on screen as the result of a formula”? (3) OK, maybe this doesn't solve some general problem that you have.  I said in my post that it was tailored to the data in the question. (4) Answers aren’t supposed to ***add to*** questions; they are meant to ***answer*** them.  The OP seemed to think that this was adequate.  Can you explain why you think it isn’t?

Comment: Why, not how or what, seems important and missing.  I apologize for being abrupt.

Answer (score 8):

A general answer:

Rather than trying to fuss with the results of the CELL("format"...) function, it may be easier to use a user-defined function to return the NumberFormat property of the cell directly.

In that case, the expression "=TEXT(A1,NumberFormat(A1))" would give you the displayed value rather directly.

To enable this, you need the following in a module of the worksheet:

```
  Public Function NumberFormat(CellRange As Range) As String

  NumberFormat = CellRange.NumberFormat

  End Function
```

Answer (score 4):

The same answer but with a different function (that has worked for me):

```
Public Function DisplayText(ByVal pRange As Range) As String  
  DisplayText = pRange.Text  
End Function
```

Just use =DisplayText(A1). If you change the cell format this function will return the displayed text

Answer (score 1):

This works for me.  It is the same as the post above but includes an error check:

Step 1:  Copy and paste the following public function in a VBA module:

```
Public Function CELLTEXT(target As Range) As String
   If target.Cells.Count > 1 Then
    MsgBox "CELLTEXT function requires a single cell as an input, please try again"
     Exit Function
    Else
        CELLTEXT = target.Text
    End If
End Function
```

Step 2: Try it in your spreadsheet.  In any cell enter the formula, for example: =CELLTEXT(A1).  This will then output whatever A1 was displaying.